# jQuery - Flip DIV issues

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm creating something that helps to flip div on hover. i have created that. But the problem is in mobile resolution the the flip should happen on click not in hover. Which means, when we press on one card the card should flip and it should flip to it's default side only when we click again. Not when we click on another card.

I have added code below. Please go through it for more clarification.

```css
.nb-flip-container:hover .nb-flip-grid, .nb-flip-container.hover .nb-flip-grid {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

        
.nb-flip-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto 30px;
  perspective: 1000px;
  cursor: default;
}
    
.nb-flip-grid {
  position: relative;
  transition: 0.6s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.nb-flip-back {
  background: #fff200;
  padding:5px;
  border-radius:8px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
  backface-visibility: hidden;

  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;

  z-index: 2;
  /* for firefox 31 */
  transform: rotateY(0deg);

}
    
.nb-flip-back {
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

span {
  display: block;
  font-size: 10px;
  font-weight: $tertiary-weight;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

p {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  line-height: 18px;
}

h3 {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="nb-flip-container">
  <div class="nb-flip-grid">
     <div class="nb-flip-front">
        <img alt="" src="http://dev.netbramha.in/projects/flip-image/flip-image-21.png">
     </div>
     <div class="nb-flip-back">
        <span> User Interface </span>
        <p> This is where the design becomes </p>
        <h3> SEXY. </h3>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can't nest pure CSS like that...

Comment: Hey Jack Bashford, I have edited the css.

Comment: Can we do that?

Comment: First of all, you should place your css code inside `<style>` tags. And, do you know css @media rule? It should take care of this problem.

Comment: @jack-bashford I think he can,

Answer (score 0):

Is this saple make you happy?

```
<!-- -->
```

[Sample Link](https://jsbin.com/qawerigome/1/edit?html,css,output)

Comment: Read the question before posting an answer. 
It is asking for help with mobile, not about the flip direction.

Comment: Pleaase, View the solution now :)

Comment: And using plase word is pleasant behaviour

Comment: Explain your solution here, tell the people on the website why they should click that link that just says Sample Link. please... man

Answer (score 0):

Please keep it in mind there are many ways to solve this problem and mine is one of them. As your title specified, using jQuery is allowed to the solution.

First, we most detect we are on the mobile environment or desktop (there are many ways to do this as well) we use old solution.

JS code to detect our running enviorment:

```
 if( navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i)
 || navigator.userAgent.match(/webOS/i)
 || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)
 || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i)
 || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i)
 || navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i)
 || navigator.userAgent.match(/Windows Phone/i)
 ){
    $('body').addClass('mobile');
    //if you have one element
    $('.nb-flip-container').toggleClass('clicked');
    //if you have multiple elements to preventing all elements be flipped
    $('.nb-flip-container').on('click', function(){//or on touch
        $(this).toggleClass('clicked');
    });
  }
 else {
    $('body').addClass('not-mobile');
  }
```

CSS:

```
.not-mobile .nb-flip-container:hover .nb-flip-grid,
            .nb-flip-container.hover .nb-flip-grid {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.mobile .nb-flip-container.clicked .nb-flip-grid,
        .nb-flip-container.clicked .nb-flip-grid {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

**Explanation**: in js code, we detect our environment is mobile or not. If is mobile add a new class to the body and also add new functionality to our element to detect click (or for a better solution touch) event. When touch occurred add a new class to the element that is equal to hover effect in desktop mode.